# Two normalization constants for Dirac plain wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, dirac-equation, normalization

I stumbled across two different expressions for a Dirac plane wave function, namely
$$\psi=\sqrt{\frac{m}{EV}}ue^{-ip\cdot x}$$
and
$$\psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2EV}}ue^{-ip\cdot x}$$
where $u$ is the Dirac spinor.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different authors may choose different normalisation schemes for the same thing. They will just have slightly different constants elsewhere to compensate. These two seem to be just a constant factor away from each other.